# How to find count of rows from textArea which has a content in GWT

Tags: gwt, textarea

I have one TextArea in GWT, TextArea inside Scrollable panel is filled with content which comes from API. Sometime the content can be less or more. I want to make my Textarea to shirnk if content is less, so how do I count the total number of lines of text inside text area?

TextArea is with fixed height applied through CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The number of lines will be different depending on the system font, font size selected by a user (it will override the font size you set in CSS), and the browser. Besides, you are talking about a TextArea, so a user can type or paste more text.

The standard design approach is to keep the TextArea size constant.

If you do want to adjust it, the solution is to create a hidden element. See the details:

http://blog.gaijindesign.com/jquery-scrolltop-to-a-hidden-element/